# Авторизация instagram (получение токена)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, веб-программирование, http

Здравствуйте.

Уже несколько дней вожусь с программной авторизацией в инстаграме и сделал ее через webbrowser (язык c#). Однако код получился очень сложным, хотелось бы все это дело перевести на http запросы с помощью WebClient или ему подобных. Но при POST запросе на авторизацию постоянно появляется ошибка HTTP 403. Вроде бы все заголовки есть, куки есть, но все равно ошибка.

Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался с данной проблемой. Мне бы понять, как избавиться от этой ошибки.

Comment: Да и сам вопрос нужно закрыть: нет ни кода, ни каких-либо подробностей, только ванговать, как заметил user31688